# Warnings in a very basic Pointer Program in C

Tags: c, pointers, warnings

I've just started with pointers in c. This program gives the desired output but I am getting the below warnings when I compile it, What am I doing wrong?

```
pointer.c:3: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast 

pointer.c:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’

pointer.c:8: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

pointer.c:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

And my code is:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
  int *x=2, *ampx, *starampx, starx;

  printf("x=");
  printf("%d\n",x);

  ampx=&x;
  printf("&x=");
  printf("%d\n",&x);

  starampx=*ampx;
  printf("*&x=");
  printf("%d\n",starampx);

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You should ask 1 question at a time.  You are asking multiple questions at once which is why I think this question should be closed.  I don't agree with H2C03 about trivial questions, but I believe all of these have been covered already on SO if they were one question each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is why:

1. `initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast` - `int *x = 2, ...` should be `int x = 2, ...`
2. `incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’` - You need to add an `#include <stdio.h>` line at the top
3. `assignment from incompatible pointer type` - This will be fixed by the #1 change
4. `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast` - `*starampx` should be `starampx` in the declaration.

In addition, printing pointers should be done with `%p` specifier, not `%d`:

```
printf("%p\n",&x);
```

Here is your fixed program on ideone: [link](http://ideone.com/6aGz00).

Answer (score 4):

```
 int *x=2
```

is actually causing your program to have undefined behavior. It tells the compiler to point at an address `2`, which may or may not be valid and derferencing the pointer will causes an undefined behavior.
Whenever you are using pointers, You need to make the pointer point to a valid memory big enough to store a `int` before you can store anything. So you either need:

```
int i = 2;
int *x = &i;
```

or you simply use:

```
int x = 2;
```

Considering, how you use `x` later in the program the latter is what you need.

You need to include `stdio.h` which tells the compiler that `printf` is an standard c library function.

Comment: It is defined in C -- x will point to location 2.  I will probably give an access violation if you try and use it, but it is defined.

Comment: @Hogan: Edited for clarity.

Comment: Better, it will *cause* undefined behavior.  I like it.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, in this statement, you have a problem.

```
int *x=2, *ampx, *starampx, starx;
     ^           ^
     |           |
```

`*x` is a pointer. To store the value of `2`, you would need to allocate space for the same. Instead of the current implementation, please try with

```
int x=2, *ampx, starampx, starx;
```